# When copying single player world to server, I lose my structures!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to copy my customized pvp map that I made in single player, I lose all of the structures that I have created. It is very frustrating as I put some serious time and effort into creating the map. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you copying the map?

Comment: Are you looking at the same coordinates? You might have spawned in a different part of the map.

Comment: It is possible that you didn't actually copied the map so the terrian (chunks) is regenerated according to your seed.

Comment: Are you setting the world in the config file to the name of your map? As fredley says, how are you copying it?

Answer (score 2):

Please check in the server.properties if **world_name** is the same as the name of the world folder which the world is in (e.g. if the name of the world is "*Mah Survival Map*", world_name has to be "*Mah Survival Map*" too.)